# How to get response from webservice?

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, web-services, soap

So I am trying to send my xml file to a webservice.

When I try to get the response it gives me an internal server 500 error. I tried looking it up, but I get things like:

**Make sure you set the user agent**

With this webservice i am working with I got a sample code for java, but it does nothing with user-agents. So I am thinking that it would be unluckily that it will solve my problem. The reason I haven't tried this is because i didn't exactly know how to use it in combination with Net.WebRequest.

**Set the header of the webrequest**

I have no idea what to put in that header. But apparently some people(marked it as an answer and it did solve their problem, without stating what they exactly figured out from the answer. seeing stuff like " Thanks, your code gave me an idea" and thats it the post dies.

And I got some other little changes that apparently fixed their issue's (which all of them i have tried).

**What am I trying to do?**
Well I am trying send an xml to webservice and then get a response. The response part just goes wrong, with the internal server 500 error. The webservice should send back information. Note that I am not using a web reference, because apparently the WSDL doesn't work(So there won't be a solution in there.) So I am sending my code with the help of "System.Net.Webrequest".

```
    Dim req As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url), Net.HttpWebRequest)
    req.ContentType = "text/xml"
    req.Method = "POST"
    req.ContentLength = sentXml.Length
    'the credentials are set somewhere in a string(these are correct)
    req.Credentials = creds
```

Then I proceed on writing the sentXml into getRequestStream variable. Then afterwards I call the getResponse method. And here is where it just refuses to work.

**My question:**
What should be my troubleshooting steps? Since I am new to webservices, what could I have forgotten or have done completely wrong? Anyone that could point me to the right direction would be helpful.

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your request via a Rest Console such as https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo which is an extension for Google Chrome.

Comment: I will have to try this another time, since my OS is XP and I can't install chrome version 23. So I geuss I will have to do this at home.